# How to make ui-router working inside custom Angularjs directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router

I'm trying  to create navigation tree for my application using custom directive for it. For now I have the following in my directive (minified):

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('app.layout')
    .directive('cnNavTree', ['$log', '$state', cnNavTree]);

  function cnNavTree($log, $state) {
      var directive = {
        link: link,
        restrict: 'EA',
        templateUrl: 'app/layout/cn-nav-tree.html'
      };
      return directive;

    function link(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.$on('stateChange', function (event, toState, fromState) {
        updateNavTree(event, toState, fromState)
      });

      function updateNavTree(event, toState, fromState) {
        element.html('<span class="color" ui-sref="app.twoWays">Report load</span>');
      }
    }
  }
})();
```

Everything is OK except **ui-sref in element.html**, it's not working and I cant go to *app.twoWays* state. Any ideas, how can we solve the problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It would be easier to help if you provided a reproducible example

Comment: `'$stateChangeStart'` not `'stateChange'`, and read about [$state.get](https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/0.3.1/index.html#/api/ui.router.state.$state) to generate the url from the code

Comment: @AlonEitan, it's not `$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', ...`, it's my custom `$scope.$broadcast(...)`

Comment: include $rootScope on Directive

Comment: @FelippeTadeu, i have tried to inject $rootScope, but nothings changed

Comment: my `element.html` works, except **ui-sref**

Comment: You can't manually insert directives without using `$compile()` so angular is aware of them and actually compiles them

Comment: thanks guys, `$compile()` works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As there are angular binding available on DOM. You have to `compile` the HTML element with current scope, before injected that DOM inside DOM tree.

```
//inject $compile before using it.
var compiledDOM = $compile('<span class="color" ui-sref="app.twoWays">Report load</span>')($scope);
element.append(compiledDOM);
```

Comment: I'll try it in few minutes